# Would RPI 3 serve as IoT server with MQTT?

Tags: mqtt, hardware, raspberry-pi, lorawan

I answered to the below linked question and started to think, what are the hardware specs for running an IoT stack of for example MQTT over LoraWan? Would Raspberry PI 3 survive or not?

I do not care how RPI connects LoraWan, mainly about RAM and storage use.

[How to select simple light weight IoT server for development?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/388/how-to-select-simple-light-weight-iot-server-for-development/1856#1856)

Comment: How many devices are to be connected?

Comment: I am interested to know if the server and protocol stack survive in the RPI, and bonus is that some 1 to 10 devices will send data per second.

Comment: It almost doesn't matter how many devices are connected, air-capacity limits of LoraWAN are going to limit the traffic volume to something reasonable.  Though there is a badly done design out there with internal USB latency sitting between the CPU and radio which limits the network design as it can't control the radio fast enough to make an optimally timed network.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A Raspberry Pi 3 is a pretty serious bit of kit when you think about it

- Quad core Arm Cortex
- 1gb of RAM
- a onboard GPU

That is a huge amount of memory, easily more than enough to run a MQTT broker and something like Node-RED to interface between a LoRa radio and the broker.

We have a commercial gateway (MultiTech MultiConnect Conduit) in the office which is a very similarly [spec](https://www.multitech.com/documents/publications/data-sheets/86002170.pdf)'d bit of kit and if you google loRawan gateway most of the first page is all about how to build one with a pi.